# Magento 2 - sell product grouped by quantity

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

My client want sell their product by quantity for exemple :

Flowers sell by

`10qty = 10$`,`20qty = 15$`,`30qty = 22$`

without the customer can edited the quantity salled.

And he want to manage the stock quantity by unit.

So if he had 100 flowers and he sale one group of 20 flowers, he remaind 80 flowers at the end.